# Permission denied for adb push file to /data/data/xxx/file/

Tags: adb

I used "adb pull" to backup Final Fantasy III saved data and it worked well, but it doesn't allow me to push it back after the factory reset.

```
D:\AndroidSDK\sdk\platform-tools>adb push d:\save.bin /data/data/com.square_enix.android_googleplay.FFIII_GP/files/save.bin
failed to copy 'd:\save.bin' to '/data/data/com.square_enix.android_googleplay.FFIII_GP/files/save.bin': Permission denied
```

My phone is Nexus 4 with latest stock rom (4.3), not rooted, and I don't want to root it only for a game's save files.

As a linux user, I understand the file/folder might have no 'w' permission for the adb user, but this link:

http://androidforums.com/nexus-7-gen1-2012-all-things-root/683029-titanium-backup-saved-games-can-restored.html

Says Titanium could restore the save file for Final Fantasy III, any idea how to do that with adb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Seems

```
adb shell
ran-as "package-name"
...
```

Should do the trick, but because of a bug, this cannot be done on 4.3 system.

Bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373

Comment: note: it's "run-as" you made a typo there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a developer ROM, or in any way you have "su" enabled, you could copy to the SDcard and then use the shell:

```
adb push d:\save.bin /sdcard/.
adb shell "su @ cp /sdcard/save.bin /data/data/com.square_enix.android_googleplay.FFIII_GP/files/save.bin"
```